# Virtual Directory to WordPress blog

Tags: wordpress, iis, directory, virtual

I have a website - www.domain.com - with Windows hosting. I don't want to install WordPress on Windows. Instead I want to get a WordPress blog on Linux hosting and create a virtual directory on my main server: www.domain.com/blog - which points to the WordPress blog. However, I can't find how to do this.

I have found documentation on how to create virtual directories in IIS 7.0, but this all seems to involve a directory on the same server.

Thanks, Jon

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing Make IIS a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

virtual directories are for running separate applications (different web roots, web.configs etc) on the same server as part of a single domain - so not what your looking for.

As Lex Li tersely pointed out, one option is you can use IIS as a proxy and rewrite the urls to some other host. IIS can modify the urls if nessersary so traffic appears to be served by your Windows server, when in fact IIS is making sneaky requests to the Linux blog behind the scenes and modifying the markup to ensure urls point to the Windows machine, and not the actual url which points to your linux box (your blog could be on any domain/subdomain/path and still appear to be part of yur site).

You could also use a CDN (cloudflare is free for the basic package...) and that allows you to setup rules so you can request content from different origin servers (ie your linux box) based on a prefix (`/blog` in your case), but all other traffic is sent to your Windows server.

Another option (not quiet what you asked for, but really simple to setup...) - if you can use a sub-domain instead of a prefix to the path (ie `blog.domain.com/` instead of `www.domain.com/blog`) you can just point DNS for `blog.` to your linux host and `www.` to your IIS box - no configuration required to your Windows server.

Worth noting that its pretty much always a good idea to use a CDN infront of your web servers, its a layer of protection, makes your pages load faster etc etc etc (and it would work in front of either of the other 2 options suggested above)

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive reply. Agree about virtual directories. Sub-domain is something I know we can do, but isn't what we want (as content isn't viewed as part of our domain). CDN vs proxy & rewrites - would the CDN be sufficient by itself to achieve what we want or is it only in combination with the proxy / rewrites idea? Anyway, thanks again - lots to look into.

Comment: Depending on the CDN, its do-able with just a CDN alone, but you may encounter limitations. Using IIS with UrlRewrite and Application Request Routing (ARR) modules will give you much more control. Regardless of if you decide to use a CDN's functionality for the reverse proxying, its pretty much always a good idea to put a CDN in front of your websites as it will speed up real-world page load speeds, reduce load on your server and there are typically security and performance optimisations provided by CDNs out of the box.